# Media queries - percentage for mobile and pixels for desktop?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this small social network with a couple of thousand users. The thing is that it's static at 980px - which at the time was great. Now I need to redesign the website though and want to optimize it for mobiles, tablets aswell as bigger desktops.

The website itself is very complex with a unique design, so a liquid webdesign is out of the picture. I need to have a lot of control over the elements, so I choose responsive.

I'm reading a lot about the subject and read on 99designs.com, that they target 3 specific media queries:

Small: under 600px. This is how content will look on most phones.

Medium: 600px – 900px. This is how content will look on most tablets, some large phones, and small netbook-type computers.

Large: over 900px. This is how content will look on most personal computers.

I don't understand this, because if I make a page 600px wide, my phone is showing a horisontal scrollbar.

So my question is. Should I use percentages in the mobile version of the website like:

```
#Wrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

and for the desktops (lets say for 980 px desktops):

```
#Wrap {
    width: 980px;
    float: left;
}
```

I really wished that if I designed a website in 600px, that it would automatically fit screens up to 600px, if I used:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
```

Comment: To answer your question: Yes. For styling mobile, use fluid widths like `100%`, because there are countless size variations among smartphone screens. Then you can have a fixed layout for `768px` (tablet) and keep your `980px` (desktop) the same.

Comment: 600px is still quite wide, that's why you see the scrollbar on the phone, I think. An iPhone 6 in portrait mode is about 375px, I think.

Comment: Thank you @JonUleis - I'm doing that.